# how to connect an alexa device with the alexa code in alexa developer console

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I would like to understand how to connect a device compatible with Alexa (tile) in the code of my skill. in particular I would like to create an app for the visually impaired in which the visually impaired person asks "where is the shirt" and the tile device starts playing after Alexa says "the shirt is about to play". I've already done the textual part. I would like to understand how to integrate the possibility of connecting this tile into the skill code. I would like to point out that I have already configured it in the Tile app and in the Alexa app so it is present in my account.

connect an alexa device with the alexa code in alexa developer console

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend contacting the Tile device manufacturer and/or referencing their documentation to see if they have an API you can call within your skill's code to link to a particular device.